# How can we move sprite on shaking iphone?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i have a CCsprite object (Helicopter) and it moves on the screen where ever we touch.
I want to know how to move helicopter without touch e.g it moves upward if we move the iphone upward..

what is it called and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the Motion Event API, which provides an abstracted view of the accelerometer and gyroscope (if available):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html

Comment: what do you mean by if available?

Comment: can i get example code for just to move a ball on the screen?